# Verilog Constructing synchronous 4-bit counter using negative edged JK Flip Flop testbench problem

Tags: verilog, counter, circuit, digital-design

I am constructing a 4-bit mod 12 counter
(0->1->2->...->11->0) in Verilog.

However when I try to simulate this code with testbench in Vivado FPGA, 
it doesn't seems to operate correctly. Output of the counter module always shows 0.
I tried to modify testbench codes in several ways but nothing has been changed. 
Actually I constructed 2 more counter(3-6-9 counter, 2-digit decade counter),
all counters are not simulated as I expected.

module counter3

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module counter_3(input RESET_N, input CK, output[3:0] COUNT, output[3:0] COMP);
    wire J3, K3, J2, K2, J1, K1, J0, K0;

    assign J3 = COUNT[2] & COUNT[1] & COUNT[0];
    assign K3 = COUNT[1] & COUNT[0];
    assign J2 = COMP[3] & COUNT[1] & COUNT[0];
    assign K2 = COUNT[1] & COMP[0];
    assign J1 = COUNT[0];
    assign K1 = COUNT[0];
    assign J0 = 1;
    assign K0 = 1;

    edgeTriggeredJKFF jk1(.RESET_N(RESET_N), .J(J3), .K(K3), .CK(CK), .Q(COUNT[3]), .Q_(COMP[3]));
    edgeTriggeredJKFF jk2(.RESET_N(RESET_N), .J(J2), .K(K2), .CK(CK), .Q(COUNT[2]), .Q_(COMP[2]));
    edgeTriggeredJKFF jk3(.RESET_N(RESET_N), .J(J1), .K(K1), .CK(CK), .Q(COUNT[1]), .Q_(COMP[1]));
    edgeTriggeredJKFF jk4(.RESET_N(RESET_N), .J(J0), .K(K0), .CK(CK), .Q(COUNT[0]), .Q_(COMP[0]));
endmodule
```

module edgeTriggeredJKFF

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module edgeTriggeredJKFF(input RESET_N, input J, input K, input CK, output reg Q, output reg Q_);    

    initial begin
      Q = 0;
      Q_ = ~Q;
    end

    always @(negedge CK) begin
        Q = RESET_N & (J&~Q | ~K&Q);
        Q_ = ~RESET_N | ~Q;
    end

endmodule
```

Testbench Code

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module test_tb();
    reg counter3_RESET_N;
    wire [3:0] counter3_CNT;    
    reg CK;
    integer i;
    counter_3 c3 (.RESET_N(counter3_RESET_N), .CK(counter3_ck), .COUNT(counter3_CNT));
    always #3 CK = ~CK;
    initial begin
        Passed = 0;
        Failed = 0;
        CK <= 0;  
        counter_3_test;
    end
    task counter_3_test;
    begin
    CK <= 0;
    counter3_RESET_N <= 1;
    #60 counter3_RESET_N <= 0;
    #6 counter3_RESET_N <= 1;
    #48;
    end
    endtask


endmodule
```

[image: Simulated Result]

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to pass your clock down to the DUT. Instead of `CK` you passed `counter3_ck` which has not even been declared. I suggest that you the `` `default_nettype none `` directive to catch those bugs.

On the side note, you misuse blocking and non-blocking assignments. There should be none in the `initial` block of your test bench and you should have used them in the flop of your jk module. `Q_` will not work correctly and will be late one cycle in this case. It should be combinational:

```
always @(negedge CK)
    Q <= RESET_N & (J&~Q | ~K&Q);

always @*
    Q_ = ~RESET_N | ~Q;
```

And you should always consider any `initial` block as a part of the testbench. So is your initial block in the jk module.